# Upload a file with fetch api

Tags: javascript, nginx, file-upload, fetch-api

I'm trying to upload a file with fetch api, the file that I want to send is a Zip file and I get it from a component in Polymer, I get a  `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error`, here is my code:

```
function submitImport(url, file) {
  return fetch(url,{
    headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/zip'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: file
  }).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  });
}
```

and here is where I called the method (url_import is an url from an api rest):

```
var file = this.$.zip.file;
var host = this.domHost;

submitImport(url_import, file)
  .then(function (response) {
    host.refresh();
    hideLoading();
  });
```

The api doesn't accept formData, so I have to send the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('fileToUpload', fileInput.files[0]);
  const response = await fetch('/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });
  if (response.ok) {
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('Server response:', data);
  } else {
    throw new Error('File upload failed');
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
}
```